# Как в JavaScript (canvas) работать с прямоугольной системой координат

Tags: javascript, canvas, математика, геометрия

Всем привет! я нарисовал с помощью JavaScript canvas, два прямоугольника 400px в ширину и 200px в высоту, Но проблема в том что canvas работает с экранной системой координат, а мне нужно сделать тоже самое но только использовать прямоугольную систему координат, как мне это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "прямоугольная система координат"?

Comment: http://math-prosto.ru/?page=pages/system_of_axis/system_of_axis.php

Comment: смущает то что отчет идет не от низа, а от верха?? работайте с Y по формуле  `высота канвы - Y = привычный Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все довольно просто: нужно просто переводить точки из одной системы в другую. Это делается не сложно, допустим

```
w - ширина канваса
h - высота канваса
x0 - центр по оси x
y0 - центр по оси y
x1 - x который нужно найти
y1 - y который нужно найти
```

Тогда что бы перевести координаты из одной системы в другую ( из экранной в прямоугольную ), надо воспользоваться формулой

```
x = x1 + x0
y = y1 + y0,
где x0 = w/2, y0 = h/2 =>
x = x1 + w/2
y = y1 + h/2
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const CANVAS_W = 500;
const CANVAS_H = 350;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const x0 = CANVAS_W / 2; // центр по х
const y0 = CANVAS_H / 2; // центр по y
const xInput = document.getElementById('x-value');
const yInput = document.getElementById('y-value');

// переводим из одной системы координат в другую
const scaleCoordX = x => x + x0
const scaleCoordsY = y => y + y0
const drawCircle = (x, y) => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_W, CANVAS_H);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(scaleCoordX(x), scaleCoordsY(y), 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.width = CANVAS_W;
canvas.height = CANVAS_H;
document.onchange = function (e) {
  const id = e.target.id;
  const x = +xInput.value;
  const y = +yInput.value;
  
  drawCircle(x, y);
}

drawCircle(0, 0);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<input id='x-value' placeholder='x' value='0' type='number'>
<input id='y-value' placeholder='y' value='0' tuype='number'>
<br><br>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
```